# result value changes when compiled in matlab 6.5 and 7.5

Tags: matlab

I get different results between versions 6.5 & 7.5. Here's the result for 6.5

```
corr_a1=[10 49  1   25  6   3   47  4475    20  2017    14  23  3   29  9   47  4   5   21  2019    53  6280    23  26  0   23  8   17  907 13  13  19  5   18  14  10  ];
```

and here's the result for 7.5

```
corr_a1=[6  17  0   14  3   7   18  5242    3   1271    3   7   1   4   3   14  0   0   13  1289    15  7353    17  11  2   14  1   8   893 0   7   8   0   8   2   2   ];
```

My code is as follows:

```
img1=imread(fn);%reading image

img=imresize(img1,[128 128]);

img=double(img);

img_red=img(:,:,1);

img1_red=repmat(img_red,[1 1 3]);

img_green=img(:,:,2);

img1_green=repmat(img_green,[1 1 3]);

img_blue=img(:,:,3);

img1_blue=repmat(img_blue,[1 1 3]);

siz=size(img);


%initialising color categories for image

r_maxb_min=zeros(siz);

r_maxg_min=zeros(siz);

g_maxr_min=zeros(siz);

g_maxb_min=zeros(siz);

b_maxr_min=zeros(siz);

b_maxg_min=zeros(siz);

%1=RmaxGmin
%2=RmaxBmin
%3=GmaxGmin
%4=GmaxBmin
%5=BmaxRmin
%6=BmaxGmin

%representation of image with color categories

for row=1:siz(1)

        for col=1:siz(2)

       r=img_red(row,col);

       g=img_green(row,col);

       b=img_blue(row,col);

        a1=[r,g,b];

        if (max(a1)==r) & (min(a1)==g)

          r_maxg_min(row,col)=r_maxg_min(row,col)+img(row,col);

          img(row,col)=1;

          elseif (max(a1)==r) & (min(a1)==b)

          r_maxb_min(row,col)=r_maxb_min(row,col)+img(row,col);

          img(row,col)=2;

        end

        end
end



for row1=1:siz(1)

        for col1=1:siz(2)

       r1=img_red(row1,col1);

       g1=img_green(row1,col1);

       b1=img_blue(row1,col1);

        a2=[r1,g1,b1];

        if (max(a2)==g1) & (min(a2)==r1)

         g_maxr_min(row1,col1)=g_maxr_min(row1,col1)+img(row1,col1);

         img(row1,col1)=3;

          elseif (max(a2)==g1) & (min(a2)==b1)

          g_maxb_min(row1,col1)=g_maxb_min(row1,col1)+img(row1,col1);

          img(row1,col1)=4;

        end

        end
end



for row2=1:siz(1)

        for col2=1:siz(2)

       r2=img_red(row2,col2);

       g2=img_green(row2,col2);

       b2=img_blue(row2,col2);

        a3=[r2,g2,b2];

        if (max(a3)==b2) & (min(a3)==r2)

         b_maxr_min(row2,col2)=b_maxr_min(row2,col2)+img(row2,col2);

         img(row2,col2)=5;

          elseif (max(a3)==b2) & (min(a3)==g2)

          b_maxg_min(row2,col2)=b_maxg_min(row2,col2)+img(row2,col2);

          img(row2,col2)=6;

        end

        end
end


b_maxr_min;
b_maxg_min;
g_maxr_min;
g_maxb_min;
r_maxg_min;
r_maxb_min;

set1=[r_maxg_min r_maxg_min g_maxr_min g_maxb_min b_maxr_min b_maxg_min];

result=img(:,:,1);

siz_res=size(result);

img1;

result;

%constructing color corellogram

max_res=max(max(result));

corr=zeros(max_res,max_res);

dy=1;
dx=0;
for row=1:siz_res(1)-dx

    for col=1:siz_res(2)-dy

        i=result(row,col);

        j=result(row+dx,col+dy);

         corr(i,j)=corr(i,j)+1;

        end

    end

corr;
corr_a1=corr(:)';
```

Comment: Please do not post a wall of code. We don't have time to read through it. If you have a minimal example that reproduces your error, then please post that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is going wrong in both versions, but here are some remarks and tips on how to solve this:

- I'd personally use `im2double` if that's available in both versions
- In solving your problem, you could try to narrow down where the problem is, most likely the error might be somewhere at the beginning, propagating all through your code and giving an incorrect output.

Practically I see that last step as follows: you run the code both in MATLAB 6.5 and MATLAB 7.5 simultaneously. However, between each large segment of code, you put `%%`. In MATLAB 7 this allows you to run this code in "cell mode", such that you can easily execute only that cell (segment) of code.

In MATLAB 6.5 you will have to emulate that behavior (you can however leave the `%%` in your code as visual cues) by manually executing parts of the code. You start by executing the first cell and then you export your workspace variables from MATLAB 6.5:

```
 save();
```

And in MATLAB 7.5 you import the same variables as a struct:

```
 matlab65 = load();
```

There you can do comparisons on each variable to see whether they are still equal. Completely automated that might (read: untested code) look like:

```
 matlab65 = load();
 fields = fieldnames(matlab65)
 for iField = 1:numel(fields)
     variable = fields{iField};
     if any((eval(sprintf('%s ~= matlab65.%s',variable,variable))))
         fprintf(1,'%s is not equal',variable);
     end
 end
 clear fields variable iField
```

If they are not equal, you know that the problem is somewhere in the code you already executed (and that you want to focus on the variables that are not equal). If the variables are equal, just proceed by executing the second cell in both versions and importing your old results to the new MATLAB as before.

By doing so, you can track the error down to a single cell of code and then you can use the debugger (in both MATLAB versions) to track down the error in your code cell.

You can also apply the well-known dichotomy strategy: i.e. split your code into two cells (of approximate equal size) and run the procedure below: you will either find that there is an error in the first part or second part (when all variables in part1 are equal). Repeat the procedure by dividing the part of your code that contains an error into two parts.